# Share HD between laptop and Panasonic TV

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, tv

I have a 1TB Western Digital USB external hard drive, which I originally wanted to use solely with my Panasonic Viera TV for recording missed programs, etc. This setup was fully functional, but I now want to do more with the hard drive - like store backups of my files which are on my laptop (Windows 7)

According to [this link](http://www.avforums.com/forums/lcd-led-lcd-tvs/1303759-panasonic-viera-tv-usb-hdd-pvr-supported-drives-pc-access-recordings.html), the TV runs a version of FreeBSD and uses the UFS2 file system, which isn't supported by Windows. Plugging the hard drive into the laptop after being formatted by the TV requires it be formatted back to FAT.

I tried partitioning the hard drive using the laptop, hoping that the two partitions would show up as two separate devices on the TV but this did not work. How can I get the hard drive to be shared and used for both devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably out of luck.  You did the logical thing by partitioning the drive, but it didnt work.  More than likely this is due to Panasonic checking to see if the hard drive has been altered after it formats it.  They do this to prevent people from pirating copyrighted content.

I wouldnt waste time trying to get this working. It will be far easier to just to buy another external HDD for your backups.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2):

There is quite a range of freeware available to allow you to read a UFS2 file system im sure with one of these you would be able to access the data, or think about using a linux live cd on your laptop (not the easiest way but if you only want to get data off it once a week or something would work)

Answer (score 1):

ufs2tools contains tools for reading ufs (ffs) filesystems and bsd labels from windows 2000/XP. Both ufs1 and ufs2 are supported.

ufs2tool is a program for reading ufs filesystems from windows. You can retrieve files and directories recursively. You can also list directories. bsdlabel is a program to read bsd labels. Only BSD UFS is supported (other implementations such as Solaris UFS will not work).

http://ufs2tools.sourceforge.net/